# Problemas com a criação do recaptcha na área de login do meu sistema web

Tags: php, html5

Olá, estou seguindo os passos do google para criar um recaptcha na área de validação e login do sistema.

Estou inserindo nos lugares certos, do meu código, as chaves geradas no google. Porém o recaptcha não está funcionando. Quando eu insiro a senha e login e não clico (marco a caixa) no recaptcha, o usuário consegue entrar no sistema normalmente. Ou seja, o recaptcha está ali só de enfeite.

Vou postar o código pra ver se vocês me ajudam.(OBS: Mudei as chaves geradas no google para o meu sistema)

Desde já, agradeço a atenção. Obrigado!

```html
<?php
 
 
 session_start();
 //CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
 require_once("banco/conexao/conexao-com-banco.php"); 
 require_once("banco/atualizador/atualizador-tarefas-web.php"); 
 require_once("banco/atualizador/corretor.php"); 
 require_once("banco/validador-de-login/validador-login.php"); 
 
 
?>


  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>

  <head>
    <title>T-GET</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="_jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ARQUIVO JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    <link href="_css-index/pagina-login/estilo-telalogin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- ARQUIVO CSS DO -->
    <link href="_bootstrap4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- ARQUIVO CSS DO BOOTSTRAP -->

  </head>


  <body>

    <!-- INTRODUÇÃO VIDEO - ANDREWS-->

    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #0275d8;">

      <div class="row" id="row-corpo">



        <!-- DIV COM O FORMULÁRIO DE LOGIN -->
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5" id="titulo-sistema">


          <header>
            <label style="color:gold; font-family:roboto; font-size:30px">T-GET</label>
            <img src="_imagens/logo-azul.png">
          </header>



        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5" id="formulario">

          <form action="banco/validador-de-login/validador-login.php" method="post" id="formulario-login-sistema">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="login">Usuário:</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Digite seu usuário" required autofocus />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="senha">Senha:</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="password" id="senha" name="senha" title="A senha deve conter letras, números e caracteres especiais" placeholder="Digite sua senha" pattern="^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$])[a-zA-Z0-9@#$]{8,50}$" required
              />
            </div>

            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="5LeniaQUAAAAAN6OmP3gg3s96j4kl6ee6re6r56t66ky6k2y"></div>


            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">

          </form>

          <div id="mensagem">
            <h5>
              <?php echo $mensagem ?>
            </h5>
          </div>

        </div>



      </div>



    </div>

    <script src="_jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ARQUIVO JQUERY -->


  </body>
  <!-- FIM DO BODY -->

  </html>
  <!-- FIM DO HTML -->


  <!-- ARQUIVO validador-login.php (que é o arquivo onde rola a validação do usuário para adentrar no sistema -->


  <?php
 
 //$usuario = $_POST["login"];
 $usuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'login', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //Depois trocar para o tipo de filtro que o campo será [Email por exemplo]
 //$senha = $_POST["senha"];
 $senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //Depois trocar para o tipo de filtro que o campo será [Se for aceitar caracteres, por exemplo]
 
 $ch = curl_init();
 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
 
  "secret"=>"5LeniaQUer6hh14j15er65gfjh6g5gf4g5f4",
  "response"=>$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"],
  "remoteip"=>$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
  
 )));
 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 
 $recaptcha = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
 
 curl_close($ch);
 
 
 if($recaptcha["success"] === true)
 {
 
  //CONSULTA DE LOGIN DO USUÁRIO "CONSULTA NA TABELA tbl_usuarios"
  $mensagem = "";
  
  if (isset ($_POST["login"]))
  {
    
   $login = "SELECT * ";
   $login .= "FROM tbl_usuarios ";
   $login .= "WHERE usuario = '{$usuario}' AND senha = '{$senha}' ";
   
   $acesso = mysqli_query($conecta, $login);
   
   
   if( !$acesso )
   {
    die("Falha na Consulta ao Banco de Dados");
   }
  
   $informacao = mysqli_fetch_assoc($acesso);
   
   if( empty($informacao) )
   { 
    if(isset ($_POST["enviar"]))
    {
     $mensagem = "Login Sem Sucesso";
    }  
   }
   
   else
   {     
    $_SESSION["user_portal"] = $informacao["codigo"];
    $_SESSION["nome"] = $informacao["funcionario"];
    $_SESSION["departamento-usuario"] = $informacao["departamento"];
    $_SESSION["empresa-origem-usuario"] = $informacao["EMPRESA_ORIGEM"];
    
    verificaVencidos($conecta, $informacao["funcionario"]);
    atualizaDataPadrao($conecta);
    corrige($conecta, $informacao["funcionario"]);
    
    unset($informacao);
    
    header("location:cadastrar-empresas.php"); 

    
   }
   
  }
 }
 else
 {
  $mensagem = "Falha no Recaptcha";
  
 }

 
?>
```

**Imagem do Sistema**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O Recaptcha é um iframe? Se for vc não consegue mudar o CSS, ai a solução seria aumentar um pouco a largura do container

Comment: Não, @hugocls, o problema não é em relação ao layout do recaptcha. O problema é que ele não está funcional.

Comment: Ta certo, eu bati o olho na imagem e já achei que esse seria o problema rss. De qq forma, nessa não consigo te ajudar :/

Comment: De qualquer forma, obrigado!